# How to get the number of replications of a pattern and use it

Tags: python, regex

For example, there is a string like `aaaaaab`, where `a` repeats n times (in this case, n=6). How could I get the number n ?

Then if I want to use the n to replace it by make  `a` to n/2 times like `aaab`, or n-2 times `aaaab`. How to do with it ?

Answer (score 7):

```
s = 'aaaaabbcdddddddd'
[(m.group(1), len(m.group(2))+1) for m in re.finditer(r'(\w)(\1*)', s)]
```

returns

```
[('a', 5), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('d', 8)]
```

To use this to replace the character groups:

```
re.sub(r'(\w)(\1*)', lambda m: m.group(1)*f(len(m.group(2))+1), s)
```

with:

```
f = lambda x: x - 2 # returns 'aaadddddd'
f = lambda x: x / 2 # returns 'aabdddd'
f = lambda x: x + 1 # returns 'aaaaaabbbccddddddddd'
```

Comment: this answer is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with regular expressions alone. But you can use a regular expression to extract the string of `a`'s and then check its length.

Then you can create a replacement string of the appropriate length and do a replace.

Comment: this is not an answer, should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

To replace a **literal** pattern that appears `n` times with the same pattern repeated `n/2` times you can do:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'aaaaaab'
>>> re.sub('aa', 'a', text)
'aaab'
```

If the pattern is not a literal match this does not work and there is no way to make it work using only regexes. The thing you can do is to use `re.finditer`, and, given the information in the matches replace them with what you want.

For example, to replace with `n/2` occurrences you can do:

```
>>> text = 'aaaaaab something else aaaab'
>>> matches = list(re.finditer('a+', text))
>>> displ = 0
>>> for match in matches:
...     num_repeat = match.end() - match.start()  #depending on the pattern
...     text = text[:match.start() - displ] + 'a' * (num_repeat // 2) + text[match.end() - displ:]
...     displ += num_repeat // 2
... 
>>> print text
aaab something else aab
```

Or to replace with `n-2` occurrences:

```
>>> text = 'aaaaaab something else aaaab'
>>> matches = list(re.finditer('a+', text))
>>> displ = 0
>>> for match in matches:
...     num_repeat = match.end() - match.start()
...     text = text[:match.start() - displ] + 'a' * (num_repeat - 2) + text[match.end() - displ:]
...     displ +=  2
... 
>>> print text
aaaab something else aab
```

Answer (score 0):

> For example, there is a string like aaaaaab, where a repeats n times
>   (in this case, n=6). How could I get the number n ?

If you know which character you want to check, and want just the number of repeats:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(i for i in 'aaaaaabbbbbbc')['a']
6
```

If you want to know which characters were repeated and for how many times:

```
>>> [{k:v} for k,v in Counter(i for i in 'aaaaaabbbbbbc').iteritems() if v > 1]
[{'a': 6}, {'b': 6}]
```